# Python threading exiting

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a sqs queue of files that I want to download from my s3 so I can extract the text, but the code seems to always exits with no errors when I try to open my s3 bucket.

```
class MultiThread:

    def __init__(self):
        conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
                                      aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
        self.sqs_q = conn.get_queue(QUEUE_NAME)
        self.count = 0

    def start(self, num_threads):

        for i in xrange(num_threads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(self.do_work,))
            t.start()


    def run(self, func):
        while self.sqs_q.count() > 0:
            try:
                rs = self.sqs_q.get_messages()
                m = rs[0]
                msg = m.get_body()
                func(msg)
                self.sqs_q.delete_message(m)
            except:
                print "empty"

    def do_work(self, file_name):
        doc = DocsScrapper(file_name)
        text = doc.get_text()


class DocScrapper:

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                               aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

        bucket = conn.get_bucket('courtspider')
        doc_key = bucket.get_key(file_name)
        doc_key.get_contents_to_filename('doc/' + file_name)

    def get_text(self):
        doc_file = open('doc/' + self.file_name, 'rb')
        txt_doc = TextExtractor(doc_file)
        text = txt_doc.pdf_to_text()
        doc_file.close()
        os.remove('doc/' + self.file_name)
        return text
```

and yes the s3 bucket and files exist.

Comment: how do you know whenever your threads finished?

Comment: @DanielSanchez If I run 5 threads, it simply runs like a 1 thread app. When it hits `threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(self.do_work,))` it calls run() without creating n number of threads, then fails when I use `boto.connect_s3` methods like `get_bucket()`. After that it goes back to start() and creates another single thread, and repeats this flow the number of threads I passed. Maybe an infinite loop?